# Why did I not get my badge?

Tags: support, badges

[image]

Its been weeks since I asked 5 well received questions, but I haven't yet received the [Curious](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/curious) badge. Can anybody tell me the reason to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements for that badge are five well-received questions, and a [positive question record](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24803/311665). You've fulfilled the first requirement, but not the second.

You seem to be pretty close to even, so it shouldn't take many more well-received questions to fulfill that requirement, as long as you can avoid poorly-received questions.